# Plotting prediction intervals for mixed effects model

Tags: r, ggplot2, prediction, modeling, lme4

I have implemented a mixed effects model for my experiment for how error rate affects reaction time. I now want to calculate prediction intervals and then plot them.

Here is an example of my df

```
    ppid error_rate      RT pNum
1   1_1_4   2.865371 0.43339    1
2  1_1_77  11.459301 0.45000    1
3  1_1_80   2.865371 0.38320    1
4  1_2_26   3.820155 0.49990    1
5  1_2_31   2.865371 0.56680    1
6  1_2_32   3.820155 0.58330    1
7  1_2_33   2.865371 0.50000    1
8  1_2_40   3.820155 0.44980    1
9  1_2_43   2.865371 0.56660    1
10 1_2_54  11.459301 0.46670    1
11 1_2_63   2.865371 0.43350    1
12 1_2_64   2.865371 0.46680    1
13 1_2_71   2.865371 0.54990    1
14 1_2_76   2.865371 0.48350    1
15 1_2_85   2.865371 0.53340    1
16 1_2_88   3.820155 0.43340    1
17 1_2_89   3.820155 0.53320    1
18  1_3_0   3.820155 0.45080    1
19  1_3_1   2.865371 0.45022    1
20 1_3_19   2.865371 0.46651    1
```

I then implement the mixed effects model, generate some prediction intervals for each data point and then combine my original data with the predictions:

```
library(lme4)
library(merTools)
library(ggplot2)

fit <- lmer(formula = RT ~ error_rate + (1 + error_rate | pNum), data = data)

pred <- cbind(data, predictInterval(fit, data))
```

I then plot this using ggplot and get the following plot:

```
ggplot(pred) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = error_rate, y = fit)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = error_rate, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), alpha = .2) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x = error_rate, y = RT), alpha = .1) +
  ylab("RT")
```

[image: image of the resulting ggplot code]

My plot makes sense to me: I have the black line indicating the predicted values for each error rate, and a shaded area which denotes the intervals. However I'm unsure why I'm getting the straight vertical lines in the middle of each error rate level within my data points? Also my horizontal prediction line seems wonky... does anybody know why this might be, and how to eradicate it? Many thanks!

Comment: If you run `table(pred$error_rate)` you will see only 3 unique values. The lines seem to be connecting those points. Also, the code throws an error, `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'FirstSteeringTime' not found`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas sorry the error is because I had switched the variable names - FirstSteeringTime should be RT (edited in the example now). So to get rid of the connecting points, I could maybe simulate new data over a large range of error rates rather than the three I have got?

Comment: Maybe you can settle for mean lines? See my answer.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I see, so by averaging the fit within each error rate, I end up with one value per error rate and thus a straight horizontal line rather than vertical lines. Makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to have a line connecting the `error_rate` values without the vertical lines, is to plot *mean* values of the `y` variable `fit`. This is done with `stat_summary` as below.

```
ggplot(pred, aes(x = error_rate, y = fit)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = error_rate, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x = error_rate, y = RT), alpha = 0.1) +
  ylab("RT")
```

[image]

**Note:** In the question code, the ribbon is plotted with `alpha = 0.2` and the points with `alpha = 0.1`. Would it make more sense to have the points less transparent than the underlying prediction band? And therefore to swap the alpha values?

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but let's say you want to plot a new prediction based on the lmer model you have created. For instance, in the plot you have plotted the lmer and standard error from ~2.5 to ~10.5. How can you extend the prediction from your lmer model, for example from (0,2.5) and (10.5,15)? Do you need to create a new data frame ? Thanks.

Comment: @Rachel You can create a data.frame, then `predict(fit, newdata = new_df)` to have the response values. Create a new column in the new df,in a similar way you have in the question, `cbind(...)` and plot with `geom_point(data = new_df, aes(etc))`.

Comment: pfff I am stuck hehe could you please help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71210932/broom-mixed-exp-model-predictions