# Broom.mixed exp model predictions

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, broom

I would like to ask for some help with plotting prediction values from my model as well as the equations generated by the estimation of the lmer().

So, the data that I have is the mass volume of different rats across different days. Each rat has different time points where they took the measurement of that volume.

So, then the model that I use is :

```r
 m1 <- lmer(lVolume ~ Country*Day + (1|Rat))
```

I do this because I am interested in `exp(fitted)` values and then obtaining an exponential approach for this model instead of using a nonlinear mixed effect model (for the moment)

To plot the predictions from this model, my attempt was:

```r
m1%>% 
  augment() %>% 
  clean_names() %>% 
  ggplot(data = .,
         mapping = aes(x = day,
                       y = exp(l_volume),
                       group = rat)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = exp(fitted)),
             color = "red") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = exp(fitted)),
            color = "red") + 
  expand_limits(x = 0 , y = 0)
```

Here I plotted more rats but, as you can see the (0,0) is too far from the predictions of the lmer. I was wondering how I plot the prediction that my model is generating to see points from (0,200). I tried a hint from here by creating a new data frame and then plot using again predict(m1, newdata = new_df), but I am clueless how to create this data frame since I have 20 rats and I do not know how to expand this to the predict().

My attempt:

```r
pframe <- data.frame(Day=seq(0, 200, length.out=101))

pframe$continuous_outcome <- predict(m1, newdata = pframe, level = 0)
ggplot(data, aes(Day,lVolume)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data=pframe)
```

but I got an error:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Rat' not found

And, also is there a way to plot also the equations that you generate from each estimation, i.e, from each rat you have a set of estimators fixed and random, how can I plot the equation (red curves) that the lmer is generating for each of the rats?

Comment: not sure what your last paragraph means. `coef(m1)` will give you the intercept and slope for each rat ...

Comment: Sorry again... I am quite new to programming this type of model hehe and I really appreciate your help since I am alone doing this. So from here, again I got the red estimated curves predicted by my model, so now how can I plot a single curve that shows the median per country, so like now trying to plot the curves from raw data but now in red the Madian curve (just one per country) that represents the median predicted curve by the model per country (so in total having 2 red curves one per country)

Comment: If you use `expand.grid(Country= unique(Country), Days = 0:150)` (that's not exact, but the general idea) and then use `re.form = NA` when predicting that should give you the population-level predictions by Country.

Comment: Hi Rachel, the next time you ask a question here, please consider providing the data in a machine readable form. For example, by editing your question and pasting the output of `dput(dat0)` into the question. That way, Ben Bolker wouldn't have had to spend many minutes doing that manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be easier to use `predict` than `broom.mixed::augment`.

### construct predictions

(all combinations of Rat/Country/Days 0-150 (taking day up to 200 led to some extreme predictions that blew the vertical scale)

```r
library(tidyverse)
dc <- distinct(dplyr::select(dat1, Rat, Country))
pframe <- (with(dat1,
                expand_grid(Rat = unique(Rat),
                            Day = 0:150))
  %>% full_join(dc, by = "Rat")
  %>% mutate(lVolume = predict(m1, newdata = .))
)
```

Combine data and predictions into a single data frame (you don't have to do this but it makes the legend easy)

```r
comb <- dplyr::bind_rows(list(data = dat1, model = pframe),
                       .id = "type")
```

Plot:

```r
ggplot(comb, aes(Day, exp(lVolume), colour = type)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(group = interaction(type, Rat))) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "red"))
```

---

Reconstructing data:

```r
dat0 <- list(
    list("rat1", vol=c(78,304,352,690,952,1250), days = c(89,110,117,124,131,138), country = "Chile"),
    list("rat2", vol=c(202,440,520,870,1380), days = c(75,89,96,103,110), country = "Chile"),
    list("rat3", vol=c(186,370,620,850,1150), days = c(75,89,96,103,110), country = "Chile"),
    list("rat4", vol=c(92,250,430,450,510,850,1000,1200), days = c(47,61,75,82,89,97,103,110), country = "England"),
    list("rat5", vol=c(110,510,710,1200), days = c(47,61,75,82), country = "England"),
    list("rat6", vol=c(115,380,480,540,560,850,1150,1350), days = c(47,61,75,82,89,97,103,110), country = "England"))

dat1 <- purrr::map_dfr(dat0,
                       ~ data.frame(Rat = .[[1]],
                                    lVolume = log(.$vol), Day = .$days,
                                    Country = .$country))
m1 <- lmer(lVolume ~ Country*Day + (1|Rat), data = dat1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed like shrinking the data in the sense of only using the colms that are necessary for the model was very helpful! I got the production until 170 because 200 it went crazy hehe  Quick question regarding the second part of my post. Is it possible to label the equation generated by the lmer model, in the sense that the lmer already has the fixed and effect models, but is it possible to represent them as y = bet + rand+ error with the values of the model and plot them inside the plot ?

Comment: For example, I created a table of my estimates my this model with :
tab_model(
  m1,
  show.ci = FALSE, 
  show.se = TRUE, 
  auto.label = FALSE, 
  string.se = "SE",
  show.icc = FALSE,
  dv.labels = c("Complex REWB", "Simple REWB", "Mundlak")
) But I don't know if these estimates can be plot as equation by the lmer inside the plot of the predictions ?

Comment: I don't really know either.  Post as a new question? IIRC there is something like this for linear (`lm`) models but I don't know if anyone has extended it to LMMs.